# ASP.NET MVC - How can I get the Namespace In Custom Authorization Filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I have to implement the Custom Authorization Filter.

(for check Is Authorized, need Namespace, Controller Name, And Action Name)

I don't manage to Get the Namespace. Here's my code:

**ExampleController.cs:**

```
namespace ExampleProject.Controllers 
{
    public class ExampleController : Controller 
    {
        [CustomAuth()]              
        public string Index() 
        {        
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomAuthFilter.cs:**

```
namespace ExampleProject.Infrastructure.Filters
{
     public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
     {
          protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) 
          {
              string currentNamespace = string.Empty;
              string currentController = string.Empty;
              string currentAction = string.Empty;

              var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

              currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller"); //Example
              currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");         //Index

              currentNamespace = How???????   // ExampleProject.Controllers

              ...
          }
     }
}
```

How can I get the Namespace?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to do with namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convention over configuration

If you Observance this you can easy get  `ExampleProject.Controllers` because all controller in Controllers folder and if you don't change manually this convention you Safely to get controller's namespace but if you change namespace

```
   public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string controllerFullName { get; set; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            string currentNamespace = string.Empty;
            string currentController = string.Empty;
            string currentAction = string.Empty;

            var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

            currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller"); //Example
            currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action"); //Index
             currentNamespace = controllerFullName.Substring(0, controllerFullName.IndexOf("." + currentController, System.StringComparison.Ordinal));

            return false;
        }
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            controllerFullName = filterContext.Controller.ToString();
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }


    }
```